# Beautiful Soup can't find most of the tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this page https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search .
I am using the code below and Beautiful soup is finding only 3 tags when there are many more. I have tried using html5lib, lxml and HTML parsers but none of them have worked.

Can you advise what might be the problem please?

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set the URL
url = 'https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search'

# Connect to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse HTML and save to a BeautifulSoup object¶
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")

# soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html5lib")
# soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
# soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

# loop through all a-tags
for a_tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    if 'title' in a_tag:
        if a_tag['title'] == 'Download Document':
            link = a_tag['href']
            download_url = 'https://ntrs.nasa.gov' + link
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url,'./'+link[link.find('/citations/')+1:11])
```

Comment: If you can't find elements with BS that you're seeing in your browser, it's possible that the page is being loaded dynamically with JavaScript. See [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python). I recommend using `requests_html` or `selenium`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that the page is rendered using Javascipt, and the actual page source is only a few script and style tags.

Answer (score 1):

It is dynamically pulled from a `script` tag. You can regex out the JavaScript object which contains the download url, handle some string replacements for html entities, parse as json then extract the desired url:

```
import requests, re, json

r = requests.get('https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search')
data = json.loads(re.search(r'(\{.*/api.*\})', r.text).group(1).replace('&q;','"'))
print('https://ntrs.nasa.gov' + data['http://ntrs-proxy-auto-deploy:3001/citations/search']['results'][0]['downloads'][0]['links']['pdf'])
```

You could append the `?attachment=true` but I don't think that is required.